# extract time series weather forecast data from Netcdf to csv

Tags: r, matlab, csv, netcdf, weather

I want to use R to extract a time series data from Netcdf dataset at every location(X and Y) and convert it to csv file. This is my first time dealing with NetCDF data. Could anyone tell me the related code using R or Matlab?

Here is my data description:

IRI FD Seasonal_Forecast Precipitation prob: Tercile Probability data

Independent Variables (Grids):

Tercile Classes
grid: /C (ids) unordered [ (Below_Normal) (Normal) (Above_Normal)] :grid
Month Forecast Issued

grid: /F (months since 1960-01-01) ordered [ (Sep 1997) (Dec 1997) (Mar 1998) ... (Sep 2015)] N= 187 pts :grid

Forecast Lead Time in Months
grid: /L (months) ordered (1.0 months) to (4.0 months) by 1.0 N= 4 pts :grid
Longitude (longitude)

grid: /X (degree_east) periodic (178.75W) to (178.75E) by 2.5 N= 144 pts :grid
Latitude (latitude)

grid: /Y (degree_north) ordered (88.75N) to (88.75S) by 2.5 N= 72 pts :grid

Comment: Have you tried the package `ncdf`?

Comment: With matlab your can read a netcdf with the library `ncdf` and then export the result in .csv with `csvwrite`

Answer (score 1):

you can use netcdf4 packages

```
library(ncdf4)
setwd("E:\\KKIM_2017\\DES\\")

nc = nc_open("MTS_IR_201612010000.nc")       #open ncdf and read variables
lon = ncvar_get(nc,"longitude")              # Lon lat and time
lat = ncvar_get(nc,"latitude")
time = ncvar_get(nc, "time")
dname = "IR"  #variable
variabel = ncvar_get(nc,dname)
lonlat = as.matrix(expand.grid(lon,lat))
var_vektor = as.vector(variabel)
datanya = data.frame(cbind(lonlat,var_vektor))
names(datanya) = c("lon","lat",paste(dname,as.character(), sep="_"))
head(na.omit(datanya))
csvpath = "E:\\"  #directory to save file
csvname = "hasil_1v2.csv" #file_output
csvfile = paste(csvpath, csvname, sep="")
write.table(na.omit(datanya),csvfile, row.names=FALSE, sep=",")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and thanks for your contribution! Would be great if you still could translate the few Indonesian words to English. Thanks!